# How do I Sort a column based on the has many field in cakephp 2.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have the following relationships in my models

State has many LGA.

LGA has many WARDS.

I am displaying a paginated list of states and one of the column contains LGA and another contains WARD. I can sort by state and LGA but I am unable to sort by WARD.

Cake returs a **Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Ward.name' in 'order clause'**

I can see in the resulting sql query, that cake is simply adding the ward.name to the order by clause without it being in the actual joins for the query.

Has anyone experienced this? How did you solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: cake creates another query for one to has many. you need to add the order to the Contain.

Comment: Hi Sela, I am not using contain I am using the default $this->Paginator->paginate() in the controller. I only pick the display field from the result set from paginate().

Comment: can you share your code? if you have association from State to LGA you can sort to WARDS. You can try the joins to your paginate.